# How to concat tensors having different shapes as [128, 1] and [1, 1]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model generates a output tensor t1 with shape[128,1], I want to concat another tensor t2 with shape [1 ,1].
Is there any way by which I can concat tensors with different shapes?

I think solution in following link is not applicable in above scenario.
[How to concat two tensors different shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628682/how-to-concat-two-tensors-different-shape)

Answer (score 0):

By following the answer from the link, you could use `tf.reshape` applied to your tensor with shape `[128,1]`:

```
t1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [128,1])
t2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 1])
t1_reshape=tf.reshape(t1,[-1,128])
t3 = tf.concat([t1_reshape,t2],axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    t3_val = sess.run(t3, feed_dict = {t1: np.ones((128,1)), t2: np.ones((1, 1))})

print(t3_val.shape)

(1,129)
```

Comment: As expected there is an error- TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles

Comment: I don't get any error when I run the code above. So the problem is related to your own code because the error is telling you that you are trying to feed a `tf.Tensor` object in your dictionary. Note that I'm not feeding a `tf.Tensor` object in my example but rather a `np.ones` object.

Comment: Note that in my example I'm feeding `np.ones` which is a `numpy ndarrays` object. But you are feeding a `tf.Tensor` object.

Comment: Exactly,solved it by reshaping tensors and then concatenating the tensors within lambda statement. But then I am facing output shape error.