# How to append flat Tensors with differing length in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, append, tensor

I want to append two flat (1 dimensional) Tensorflow Tensors, with different length. Like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.Variable([1, 2, 3, 4], tf.int32)
tf.Variable([5, 6], tf.int32)

#should become:

tf.Variable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], tf.int32)
```

tf.concat() or tf.stack(), which doesn't work because the input tensors should have the same shape/length

How do I do this?

Comment: How about:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628682/how-to-concat-two-tensors-different-shape

Comment: Did you actually try running `tf.concat`? For example `t3 = tf.concat([v1,v2], axis=0)` should work without any issue.

Comment: I tried concat, it didn't work. I also tried it with al sorts of dimensions (0 to 2, even tough that really souldn't matter since this is a 1 dimensional array), so the solution proposed by emsiiggy wouldn't work

Comment: Can you try the above.

Comment: Just did, it unfortunately didn't work.